# Double sum involving $\max$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I was wondering how to evaluate a double sum of the form
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\max(n,m)^5}.
$$
According to mathematica this is $\pi^4/45-\zeta(5)$, so I guess this is a linear combination of $\zeta(4)$ and $\zeta(5)$, but I don't know how to relate the original sum to $\zeta(4)$

Comment: My first instinct would be to try to draw yourself a picture.  Rather than looking at all of the summands in a grid and summing horizontally and then vertically, or vice versa as vertically then horizontally... I would consider adding along diagonals or square edges and then radiating outward.

Comment: That is, if the bottom left corner is the origin, consider doing it in the order $\begin{bmatrix}\vdots&&&&\vdots&\ddots\\5&5&5&5&5&\dots\\4&4&4&4&5\\3&3&3&4&5\\2&2&3&4&5\\1&2&3&4&5&\dots\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, I really like that argument, counting it in that matrix form worked out perfectly. How would you picture it if there were more variables? Say it's $\max(n,m,j)$

Comment: The same general advice applies.  Sometimes a multivariable summation has you wanting to do rows then columns but it works out easier to do as columns then rows, or as here adding in a more exotic pattern.  Be sure to be careful so as to make sure you are still only adding the correct elements.  In the case of max(n,m,j) the same idea can apply, you just need to be more careful about the size of the next "layer" being added, in this case being of size $k^3-(k-1)^3$.  Such "looking from a different angle" also does well at constructing combinatorial arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A_1=\left\{(1,1)\right\}$ and define $A_n(n\geq 2)$ by induction
$$A_n=\left\{(k,l)\in\mathbb{N}^+\times\mathbb{N}^+:1\leq k,l\leq n\right\}-\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_{k}$$
set $f(m,n)=\frac{1}{\max(m,n)^5},$ apply Tonelli's theorem and monotone convergence theorem to counting measure on $\mathbb{N}^+\times\mathbb{N}^+,$ we obtain (note that $f$ is a constant on each $A_n$)
\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}f(m,n)=\sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty}f(m,n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{(k,l)\in A_{n}}f(k,l)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n-1)\cdot\frac{1}{n^5}=2\zeta(4)-\zeta(5)\end{align}

which is what you want.

Comment: Cool answer! I am still trying to parse this answer. So, in the definition of $A_n$, you subtracted $A_{n-1}$. Is this intended, or did you perhaps mean to subtract the union $$\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1} A_{k}$$ of all the previous sets? Thanks!

Comment: @Prism Oh yes! We should substract $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k$ instead of $A_{n-1},$ I mistyped it before and have corrected it, thanks!